# jsTree xml_data plugin not working in IE11

Tags: jstree, internet-explorer-11

The jsTree xml_data plugin is not working in ie 11. It Works great in every browser (including ie10), but not in ie11. No error messages, only the "loading" forever.

```
    $("#hierarquia").jstree({ 
       "xml_data" : {"ajax" : {"url" : "XML.asp"}},
       "plugins" : ["xml_data"]
    });
```

Anyone have experienced this? I could not find any references for jsTree and ie11 on the web until now.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the the jstree.js file there is this function:

```
(function ($) {
$.vakata.xslt = function (xml, xsl, callback) {
    var rs = "", xm, xs, processor, support;
    // TODO: IE9 no XSLTProcessor, no document.recalc
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
        var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");
        var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
        xslDoc.loadXML(xsl);
        xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;
        var xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
        xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
        xslProc.transform();
        callback.call(null, xslProc.output);

        return true;
    }
    if(typeof window.DOMParser !== "undefined" && typeof window.XMLHttpRequest !== "undefined" && typeof window.XSLTProcessor === "undefined") {
        xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
        xsl = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xsl, "text/xml");
        // alert(xml.transformNode());
        // callback.call(null, new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(rs));

    }
    if(typeof window.DOMParser !== "undefined" && typeof window.XMLHttpRequest !== "undefined" && typeof window.XSLTProcessor !== "undefined") {
        processor = new XSLTProcessor();
        support = $.isFunction(processor.transformDocument) ? (typeof window.XMLSerializer !== "undefined") : true;
        if(!support) { return false; }
        xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
        xsl = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xsl, "text/xml");
        if($.isFunction(processor.transformDocument)) {
            rs = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
            processor.transformDocument(xml, xsl, rs, null);
            callback.call(null, new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(rs));
            return true;
        }
        else {
            processor.importStylesheet(xsl);
            rs = processor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
            callback.call(null, $("<div />").append(rs).html());
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

The if

```
if (window.ActiveXObject)
```

You need to add the following to it:

```
if (window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject")
```

Hope that makes sense

EDIT:

Changed the if statement to the below, as earlier fix was causing problems on Chrome:

```
if (window.ActiveXObject !== undefined || "ActiveXObject" in window)
```

Comment: Great, Works very well! My jstree version is sligthly different:

`if(r === false && (window.ActiveXObject) {` becomes `if(r === false && (window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject")) {` but it work the same.